# Difference between words 事前に , 前もって and 早めに

Tags: word-choice

Could you please tell the difference between 事前に｛じぜんに｝,  前もって｛まえもって｝and 早めに｛はやめに｝?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**早めに** means *earlier than usual*.

Examples:

> - 私が疲れているから**早めに**帰そうとしているんだろうか、と私は思った。（内田{うちだ}春菊{じゅんきく}『犬の方が嫉妬深い』より）
>     I was thinking of getting home **earlier** because I was tired.
> - 早めに知りたいことを聞いておいた方がいいと、そんな予感がしたからだ。（畠中{はたけなか}恵{めぐみ}『百万の手』より）
>     Because I got the feeling that I had better ask out what I wanted to know **as soon as possible**.
> - 図書館に寄ろうと思って、早めに出てきたんですけれど、休館日でした。 平日に休むなんて、信じられません。 （森{もり}博嗣{ひろし}『X 03 タカイ×タカイ』より）
>     Since I thought of dropping by the library, I went off home **early**, but it was closed. Seriously, that's unbelievable it's closed on a weekday.

---

**前もって** means *beforehand*

> - ゲドはおののいた。 これほどの竜の姿を前もって語ってくれた歌や物語がどこにあったろう。 彼はあやうく竜の目に見入って、それにとらえられそうになった。 （グィン『ゲド戦記1 影との戦い』より）
>     Ged stared in awe. There was no song or tale could **prepare** the mind for this sight. Almost he stared into the dragon's eyes and was caught. (original text)
> - 人間の意志や行為が経済によって前もって決められているということだ。（今村{いまむら}仁司{ひとし}『マルクス入門』より）
>     It means that, all intention and behavior are determined **beforehand**
>     by the economy.
> - 前もって電話しなかったのは、別に理由があってのことではなかった。 ただ、父ならそれで文句も言うまいと分っていたからである。 （赤川{あかがわ}次郎{じろう}『アンバランスな放課後』より）
>     Why did I not call you? There is no special reason. But, since that's you dad, I knew you would not be angry.

---

**事前** can mean *previous*, *before*, *beforehand*. Since it's a 漢語 it means it is a bit more formal and thus it mainly appears in writing. To better grasp its meaning you can see it as 事を行う前に.

> - 液晶画面に表示された名前から、掛けてきた相手は事前に分かっていた。 摩耶｛まな｝の声を聞いて、眠気が吹っ飛んだ。 （楡{にれ}周平{しゅうへい}『フェイク』より）
>     Since the name appeared on the liquid-crystal-display I knew **before** answering the call who it was. As soon as heard the voice of Mana my doziness vanished.
> - これは、かれらがわれわれの行き先を事前に知っていたことを意味する。 ジェイムズ・ブリッシュ『二重人間スポック！』より
>     That means that they **already** knew what was our destination.
> - 原則として事前の約束のない訪問客とは会わないのが神崎の方針である。 しかし例外は存在する。 赤川{あかがわ}次郎{じろう}『死者は空中を歩く』より
>     As a rule, Kamisaki does not meet with a customer who has not taken **beforehand** an appointment.

Unlike 早めに et 前もって you can use 事前 as a noun.

---

All examples are from yourei.jp

Comment: I don't know if that's the kind of answer you're looking for but at least you have some examples.